# How to stand out a vertical plotted line in a dense series using highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have this chart that renders a 5 years of data in one time load.  And, one of its feature is that a user can add a vertical (x-axis) plotline through a button click. As you can see on the screenshot, the red vertical line was behind the dense line series.  Is there a way in highchart that this vertical line will stand out (overlays) from the series lines?
[image]

Highchart code

```
    myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift',
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'left',
            itemDistance: 10,
            borderWidth: 0,
            itemMarginTop: 0,
            itemMarginBottom: 0,
            padding: 20
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    format: '{y}'
                },
                allowPointSelect: false
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                rotation: -65,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '9px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            },
            crosshair: true,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%d %b %Y %I:%M %P'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#DDDDDD',
            gridLineWidth: 0.5
        },
        tooltip: {
            positioner: function () {
                return {
                    x: this.chart.plotLeft,
                    y: this.chart.plotTop
                }
            },
            useHTML: true,
            pointFormat: '<small><font color="{series.color}"><strong>{series.name}</strong></font>: <strong>{point.y}</strong></small><br/>',
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 8px">{point.key}</span><br/>',
            xDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',
            shared: true,
            valueDecimals: 2,
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
        },
        series: [{
            name: xTitle,
            data: dataSeries
        }]
    });
```

I tried to google it but can't seem to find any similar case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a working example replicating a similar issue?

Comment: @Sasang, I can't create a working example that will replicate a high volume of data.  But, I have this sample code which illustrate a zooming in highchart that you can zoomed in the plotted vertical line.  By clicking the Add plot line button, a red vertical line will appear behind the two series lines.  If you zoomed in further in the chart, it is clear that the red line is behind the blue and black series line. Please see this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4azu308t/23/)  Do you have an idea on how to make the red vertical line stand out from the series lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the plot line to render over the graph use the `zIndex` property of the of the `plotLines` options object. From testing it, it looks like an `zIndex` value of 3 or more will render it above the graph lines. I set it to 4 just because I see references to that value in the api docs. The updated chart `plotLines` options would look something like this:

```
chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
   value: 6.5,
   color: 'red',
   width: 2,
   id: 'plot-line-1',
   zIndex:4
});
```

I've update your jsFiddle to include these changes:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4azu308t/24/)**

Comment: this is amazing, `zIndex` is the property. I have also looked up [Highchart API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.zIndex)  Thank you so much for sharing your thoughts.